# Does offline access expire?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api

I'm using OAuth2 to get offline access to several Google services.

It looks as if the offline access expires after ~30 days?
Users will have to login again and allow offline access again.

Is this expected or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Refresh tokens do not expire. However, there are limits as too how many refresh tokens can be issued. If you hit that limit, older refresh tokens will be used, which is one case a refresh token may stop working. Another case is if you intentionally [revoke](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke) access.